# Postsharp cannot load assembly

Tags: postsharp

I use Postsharp in my project and I reference some NuGet packages. When I update package A to version 1.0.1.0 from version 1.0.0.0 but I reference package B with reference to A 1.0.0.0. Postsharp fail in build with PostSharp.Sdk.CodeModel.AssemblyLoadException: Cannot find assembly [Version mismatch]. Is there any place to tell Postsharp not to load version 1.0.0.0 but version 1.0.1.0?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

We had the same build error, albeit for a different reason. We upgraded our project to .Net 4.5.1 and Postsharp through the same exception for mscorlib. We fixed the developer build by setting the PostSharpSearchPath.

[image]

Unfortunately, I am still working on a solution for our hosted build server.

I hope this helps.

Comment: But when I update nugget package I don't have any storage to search  for old version. Yes I can do it manually but its not solution.

Comment: Understood. Our solution is temporary to get the developers back up and running. We are also pointing to the new assembly location, not old and this fixed the problem of looking for the assemble. Once I have solved this behind the build server I will repost.